# from: can't read /var/mail/jira on osx

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-jira

I have looked at other similar questions but as a python newbie I am rather stumped.

I have installed Anaconda 3 and have installed successfully a number of libraries. I recently installed the jira library (with no problems) but in the Jupyter notebook I get "ModuleNOtFoundError" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1CVf.png)

When I go to terminal and run **from jira import JIRA** I get 
from: can't read /var/mail/jira

**pip show jira** gives me
Name: jira
Version: 2.0.0
Summary: Python library for interacting with JIRA via REST APIs.
Home-page: https://github.com/pycontribs/jira
License: BSD
Location: /Users/MeadenG/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: requests, defusedxml, oauthlib, requests-toolbelt, pbr, setuptools, six, requests-oauthlib

Have I not had this problem with any other libraries and I cant find any clues in the jira library documentation. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you have to use this library? I recommend that you use jira's api interface to request via the web.

Comment: I don't. Which library do you recommend?  I just want to pull and push data into JIRA.

Comment: I didn't use the library, my operation on jira is executed by the api it provides. https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.12.0/?_ga=2.122682377.325423369.1547106501-1694962030.1540388631